# What is the probability of rolling two six sided dice and having the product be greater than 15?

Tags: probability

The dice are fair simple six sided dice. Additionally, how would you extend this and find a formula to find the probability of the product being equal to or greater than X where X is a natural number equal to or less than 36?

Comment: Any thoughts?  If all else fails, it isn't all that hard to list all $36$ possible rolls and simply count.

Comment: I can count them up but I was wondering if it is possible to derive a formula but I have no idea how.

Comment: Nothing great, that I can see.  if $i$ is the smaller of the rolls then the other, $j$ must be at least $\lceil \frac {X}i\rceil$, and of course it can't exceed $6$ so I believe that you are looking at $\max (6-\lceil \frac {X}i\rceil+1,0)$ candidates for $j$ (I'd check that ..it seems prone to an off-by-one error).  Should help automate the count.

Comment: xy > 15.  As x \<= 6 y\>=2.5~3  The faces must be at least 3.  If x = 3 the y\>5 so y = 6. That's 1.  If x=4 y \>= 4 so that's 3.  if x = 5 y\>=3 so that's 3.  if x = 6 y\>=3.  so that's 4.  A total of 1 + 3 + 3 + 4 = 11

Comment: @fleablood: It should say "if $x=5$, $y\gt3$" (not $\ge$), but you counted it correctly, anyway.